# Java - Defining a method that takes in a String and returns an array of integers with the number of each vowel

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

(Sorry for the long q in advance - just wanted to be detailed!)
Hi everyone, 
I have been struggling with getting this code to compile for so long, and I have researched everywhere (including on here!) but nothing seems to work and I keep getting errors. I have continually tweaked how I have defined my static method and what I've been putting in the main method, but now I'm at a point where I don't know what's wrong and the errors don't make sense to me. 
As it says in the title, I need to write a program containing a static method that when called, would return an array of integers depicting the number of vowels, regardless of case, in the string that is input. The a is at the 0 index all the way to u at the 4 index. So
vowelCount ("EeioOoua") would return an array of  {1, 2, 1, 3, 1}.

This problem is relevant to more people than just myself because often you want to be able to count the number of elements inside of an object and then have that organized in an array. I personally haven't seen a stack overflow question that approaches this issue quite in this way / with these parameters. Any help or direction that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Please see my code and the errors I get below:

Here is my code in full:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    class Vowels
    {
        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            vowelCount(String [] letters);
        }
        private static String [] vowelCount (String [] letters)
        {
            String [] letters = new String[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
            {
                if (letters.charAt(i) == 'A' || letters.charAt(i) == 'a')
                {
                    letters[0] = letters[0]++;
                }
                if (letters.charAt(i) == 'E' || letters.charAt(i) == 'e')
                {
                    letters[1] = letters[1]++;
                }
                    if (letters.charAt(i) == 'I' || letters.charAt(i) == 'i')
                {
                    letters[2] = letters[2]++;
                }
                if (letters.charAt(i) == 'O' || letters.charAt(i) == 'o')
                {
                    letters[3] = letters[3]++;
                }
                    if (letters.charAt(i) == 'U' || letters.charAt(i) == 'u')
                {
                    letters[4] = letters[4]++;
                }
            }
            return letters;
        }
    }
```

With the code above, I just have the two errors:

```
Vowels.java:9: error: '.class' expected
    vowelCount(String [] letters);
                         ^
Vowels.java:9: error: ';' expected
    vowelCount(String [] letters);
```

But, according to something I saw ( I think on stack overflow)

I just changed 'vowelCount (String [] letters)' to

```
String [] userInput = {"I hate this problem set"};
String [] counting = vowelCount (userInput);
vowelCount (userInput);
```

and now these are all my errors (now I have 16 errors):

```
Vowels.java:16: error: variable letters is already defined in method   vowelCount(String[])
    String [] letters = new String[5];
              ^
Vowels.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        if (letters.charAt(i) == 'A' || letters.charAt(i) == 'a')
                   ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable letters of type String[]
Vowels.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        if (letters.charAt(i) == 'A' || letters.charAt(i) == 'a')
                                               ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable letters of type String[]
Vowels.java:21: error: bad operand type String for unary operator '++'
            letters[0] = letters[0]++;
                                   ^
Vowels.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
                if (letters.charAt(i) == 'E' || letters.charAt(i) == 'e')
                           ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable letters of type String[]
Vowels.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
                if (letters.charAt(i) == 'E' || letters.charAt(i) == 'e')
                                                       ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable letters of type String[]
Vowels.java:25: error: bad operand type String for unary operator '++'
            letters[1] = letters[1]++;
                                   ^
Vowels.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                    if (letters.charAt(i) == 'I' || letters.charAt(i) == 'i')
                               ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable letters of type String[]
Vowels.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                    if (letters.charAt(i) == 'I' || letters.charAt(i) == 'i')
                                                           ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable letters of type String[]
Vowels.java:29: error: bad operand type String for unary operator '++'
                    letters[2] = letters[2]++;
                                           ^
Vowels.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
            if (letters.charAt(i) == 'O' || letters.charAt(i) == 'o')
                       ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable letters of type String[]
Vowels.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
            if (letters.charAt(i) == 'O' || letters.charAt(i) == 'o')
                                                   ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable letters of type String[]
Vowels.java:33: error: bad operand type String for unary operator '++'
                    letters[3] = letters[3]++;
                                           ^
Vowels.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                if (letters.charAt(i) == 'U' || letters.charAt(i) == 'u')
                           ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable letters of type String[]
Vowels.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
                if (letters.charAt(i) == 'U' || letters.charAt(i) == 'u')
                                                       ^
symbol:   method charAt(int)
location: variable letters of type String[]
Vowels.java:37: error: bad operand type String for unary operator '++'
                    letters[4] = letters[4]++;
```

Comment: change your parameter name to letters1 or any other but not letters,also you need to learn more of arrays because in your line 19 error it should contain an array element  letters[i]..charAt(0)

Comment: Did you go through the errors one by one? First, you're redefining the argument so there's no point in having it. Second of all, `charAt` is a method of `String`! `letters` is not a string. You can't use `++` on a string!

Comment: Using arrays for this makes it complicated. A class called "VowelCounter" would be easier. Are you stuck having to use arrays?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors here.

First, you define your static method like so:

```
private static String [] vowelCount (String [] letters) {/* rest of code */}
```

Which takes an array of strings as an argument. In your example, you give the input "EeioOoua", which is just a string.

Then, further down, you re-use the variable name of your argument, letters:

```
String [] letters = new String[5];
```

You cannot use the same variable name twice like this.

Finally, you try and increment a string:

```
letters[0] = letters[0]++;
```

This makes no sense, and it's because the array you create inside the static method should be an array of integers. After all, you want you count something using it.

Answer (score 0):

After sitting with a friend who is an expert CS person, I figured what was wrong. I had basically been using letters as both a string and an array, as well as a whole host of other silly mistakes!

Here is my solution below:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.lang.Object;

    class Vowels
    {
        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            vowelCount("I love programming");
        }
        private static int [] vowelCount (String input)
        {
            int [] vowelNum = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
            {
                if (input.charAt(i) == 'A' || input.charAt(i) == 'a')
                {
                    vowelNum[0]++;
                }
                if (input.charAt(i) == 'E' || input.charAt(i) == 'e')
                {
                    vowelNum[1]++;
                }
                if (input.charAt(i) == 'I' || input.charAt(i) == 'i')
                {
                    vowelNum[2]++;
                }
                if (input.charAt(i) == 'O' || input.charAt(i) == 'o')
                {
                    vowelNum[3]++;
                }
                if (input.charAt(i) == 'U' || input.charAt(i) == 'u')
                {
                    vowelNum[4]++;
                }
           }
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vowelNum)); 
           return vowelNum;
       }
    }
```

compiles and everything -- beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not have to use arrays. A simple class called “VowelCounter” will make things much easier. Below is a very basic Class called “VowelCounter” and it does just that, it keeps a count of the vowels. This is an alternative to using an array. If you must return an Integer array of size 5 where element 0 is the count of the number A’s, element 1 is the count of the number of E’s… etc... I added a method `GetIntegerCountsInAnArray()` to return this Integer array.  Hope this make sense and helps.

```
public class VowelCounter {

  public int A_Count = 0;
  public int E_Count = 0;
  public int I_Count = 0;
  public int O_Count = 0;
  public int U_Count = 0;

  public VowelCounter () { }

  public String toString() {
    return "A:" + A_Count + " E:" + E_Count + " I:" + I_Count + " O:" + O_Count + " U:" + U_Count;
  }

  public Integer[] GetIntegerCountsInAnArray() {
    Integer[] vowelArray = new Integer[5];
    vowelArray[0] = A_Count;
    vowelArray[1] = E_Count;
    vowelArray[2] = I_Count;
    vowelArray[3] = O_Count;
    vowelArray[4] = U_Count;
    return vowelArray;
  }
}
```

Then you can use this class below to help you count the vowels in a given string. This method creates a new `VowelCounter` object and uses it to count the vowels, then returns this `VowelCounter` object.

```
private static VowelCounter vowelCount (String inString)  {
    String stringToSearch = inString.toLowerCase();
    VowelCounter vowelCounter = new VowelCounter();
    for (char curCharacter : stringToSearch.toCharArray()) {
      switch (curCharacter) {
        case 'a':
          vowelCounter.A_Count++;
          break;
        case 'e':
          vowelCounter.E_Count++;
          break;
        case 'i':
          vowelCounter.I_Count++;
          break;
        case 'o':
          vowelCounter.O_Count++;
          break;
        case 'u':
          vowelCounter.U_Count++;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    return vowelCounter;
}
```

Finally a main method to put the Class and method to work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String testString = "EeioOoua";
  VowelCounter vc = vowelCount(testString);
  System.out.println(vc);
}
```